# Where does the exponential in the product come from?

Tags: real-analysis

In this [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985505/duplicate-how-to-prove-that-cos-pi-z-prod-n-in-mathbbz-texto?noredirect=1&lq=1) in the comment it is stated that

\begin{align*} 
\cos x &= \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( 1 - \frac{4x^2}{\pi^2 \left ( 2n-1 \right )^2} \right ) \\ &=\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left ( 1 - \frac{4x^2}{\pi^2 \left ( 2n-1 \right )^2} \right ) \\ 
&= \lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left ( 1 - \frac{2x}{\pi \left ( 2n-1 \right )} \right ) \left ( 1 + \frac{2x}{\pi \left ( 2n-1 \right )} \right ) \\ 
&=\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} \prod_{n=-N+1}^{N} \left ( 1 - \frac{2x}{\pi \left ( 2n-1 \right )} \right ) \\ 
&= {\color{magenta}{\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} \prod_{n=-N+1}^{N} \left ( 1 - \frac{2x}{\pi \left ( 2n-1 \right )} \right ) e^{\frac{2x}{\pi (2n-1)}}}}\\ 
&= \prod_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left ( 1 - \frac{2x}{\pi \left ( 2n-1 \right )} \right ) e^{\frac{2x}{\pi (2n-1)}} 
\end{align*}

I wonder how the magenta equation arises.

Comment: @MartinR Is it the color? If so, I can change it... humor me! Or is it because the equation is wrong?

Comment: Actually I would almost always *avoid* color in equations, but that is just my personal opinion, this has been discussed in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4195/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Sure, I do that too... but in this case I want to highlight which equation I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\prod_{n=-N+1}^{N} \left ( 1 - \frac{2x}{\pi \left ( 2n-1 \right )} \right )  
=  \prod_{n=-N+1}^{N} \left ( 1 - \frac{2x}{\pi \left ( 2n-1 \right )} \right ) e^{\frac{2x}{\pi (2n-1)}}
$$
because the extra factors on the right-hand side for $n$ and $1-n$ cancel each other:
$$
e^{\frac{2x}{\pi (2n-1)}} \cdot e^{\frac{2x}{\pi (1-2n)}} = 1
$$

The factors $e^{\frac{2x}{\pi (2n-1)}}$ are chosen such that the infinite product $\prod_{n=-N+1}^{N} \left ( 1 - \frac{2x}{\pi \left ( 2n-1 \right )} \right ) e^{\frac{2x}{\pi (2n-1)}}$ converges, see “elementary factors” in [Weierstrass factorisation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem).

Comment: A yeah... the negatives come in. You are right! I missed this! :)

Comment: Which factors? It still looks like that exponential term was pulled out of thin air.

Comment: @Mailbox Yes, it is indeed pulled out of thin air... and I'm still trying to figure out how on earth can someone see it but the equation now makes sense to me since the terms cancel each other. Anyway ...

Comment: @Mailbox Obviously, that exponential is there for convergence ... but how could someone think about it... no idea!

Comment: @Mailbox: Yes, the factors not “pulled out of thin air” but  chosen such that $\prod_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left ( 1 - \frac{2x}{\pi \left ( 2n-1 \right )} \right ) e^{\frac{2x}{\pi (2n-1)}}$ converges. See “elementary factors” in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem.

Comment: It all makes sense now @MartinR !! Thank you !!