# How to confirm $a_0+a_1z=z/2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: Stein]

According to Hadamard's factorization  theorem, the first factor of the Hadamard's product for $e^z-1$ can be written as in the form of $e^{a_0+a_1z}$, but how to confirm $a_0+a_1z=z/2$?

Comment: One easy way to get the product for $e^z - 1$ is to use the product for the sine function with some cleverness, for example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366844/how-can-i-deduce-cos-pi-z-prod-n-0-infty1-4z2-2n12).

Comment: Alternatively, and with less cleverness, we note when $n=1$ or $n=-1$ the product is the same, and is a specific value of the product for the $\sinh$ function which we easily get from the sine function product via $\sinh(x) = -i\sin(ix).$ You thus get a system of the form $$\begin{align}a_0 + a_1 &= c_1 \\ a_0 - a_1 &= c_2 \end{align}$$ which you can use to solve for the coefficients

Comment: A third alternative that just occurred to me is to consider the Hadamard product for the Gamma function, use this to show the product at hand is a product of two Gamma functions with offset arguments, and use the Euler Reflection Formula. Haven't checked the details, but this seems like the most fun solution.