# The computation of hadamard products of entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

The [**Hadamard factorization theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Hadamard_factorization_theorem) confirms the **existence** of Hadamard products of entire functions. But is there a feasible computational technique to find the Hadamard product of a given entire function?

My question originates from an exercise on Stein's *Complex Analysis* asking me to find Hadamard products of $e^{z} - 1$ and $\cos\pi z$. I found a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366844/how-can-i-deduce-cos-pi-z-prod-n-0-infty1-4z2-2n12), and it seems that the answer uses the characteristics of the functions themselves to get a hadamard product, and the method is not general for all entire functions.

Comment: Is there even a feasible computational technique to find all the zeros of a general entire function? That's definitely a prerequisite.

Comment: @GregMartin Well that's true; then if we know all zeros of an entire function, say $\{z_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$, then can we compute the polynomial $g(z)$ in the Hadamard product $e^{g(z)} z^{m} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{k}(z_{i})$?

Comment: Of course we have to know the order of growth of the function as well, to even write down the $E_k$. But if we have that information, then we can just compute $\log \big( f(z)/z^m\prod E_k \big)$—that step isn't hard, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If we know the zeroes, we know an inferior bounds on the order and if we know a little more (eg order not integral) we actually  would know the order; usually the hard part is finding the zeroes, as the exponential  part is much easier to deal with as we can take logarithms; also the order is easily found if we know the Taylor coefficients at a point by the standard formula

Comment: @Conrad I must be missing something trivial, for I find the exponential part not easy at all... Take the exercise above for example. I know the zeroes of $e^{z} - 1$ are $\{2\pi ni\}^{+\infty}_{n = -\infty}$, and the order is $1$, so we have $e^{z} - 1 = e^{g(z)} z \prod^{+\infty}_{\substack{n = -\infty\\n\neq{0}}}(1-\frac{z}{2\pi ni})$. Taking logarithm we get $\log{(e^{z} - 1)} = g(z) + \log{z} + \sum^{+\infty}_{\substack{n=-\infty\\n\neq{0}}}\log{(1-\frac{z}{2\pi ni})}$, then I am lost about how to proceed.

Comment: first one has to be careful as the product  on the zero is not absolutely convergent and zeroes must be grouped in pairs to get a square term; Look at growth rate on rhs which  implies $g$ is degree  $1$ at most, $az+b$; dividing by $z$ and taking the limit at zero gives $b=0$; conjugate invariance gives $a$ real and then note that the limits at $\pm \infty$ on the real axis are same except for sign (clear once you group $n$ with $-n$ in the product) and the sign is plus for $z$ positive as the factors except $z$ are sums of squares; from here you find $a$ by symmetry

Comment: @Conrad Thanks a lot for your help; now I understand that for a general entire function the hard part is actually finding all its zeros and its order of growth.

Comment: happy to be of help - the exponential part is usually a guess and check at some values (or limit on some lines) as it has few parameters only (being polynomial) when the function has finite order, especially in the usual like order $1$ where lots of familiar functions live